# Highlight border of form field in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Highlighting border of text box field with Jquery with smooth effect.
Eg. when user focuses the input box the border of the field should be highlighted with a smooth effect.
I know it can be done using css's focus property, but i dont want to use it, as it does not gives a smooth effect.

Eg references : 
1. The search box of youtube : http://www.youtube.com/
2. 99lime : http://www.99lime.com/elements/#form-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the effect smooth with CSS transitions.

```
input {
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow .3s;
    transition: box-shadow .3s;
}
input:focus {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/Zn8eZ/

There's no simple way to animate box-shadow with jQuery -- it requires a plugin.  I suppose you could superimpose the input on top of an invisible shadowy presence and animate its display though.

Comment: this is exactly i want. but can you show me how to do with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
  $('input[type="text"]').focus(function() {
   $(this).addClass("focus");
  });

   $('input[type="text"]').blur(function() {
   $(this).removeClass("focus");
  });
```

check demo here...http://jsfiddle.net/d3TbF/

Comment: when you focus on textbox...border is highlighted

Comment: its by default with the browser

Answer (score 0):

If you need jQuery, you can try this (include jQuery UI library):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("input").on('focus', function(e) {
        $(this).animate({ borderColor: "#0e7796", boxShadow: '0 0 5px 3px rgba(100,100,200,0.4)' }, 'slow');
    }).on('blur', function(e) {
        $(this).animate({ borderColor: "#ccc", boxShadow: '0px 0px 0px #fff' }, 'slow');
    });
});
```

You will have to use box-shadow animation plugin, available at: http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/shadow-animation/

Fiddle (updated): http://jsfiddle.net/vishaldeep/QgYrG/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#validate').attr('style', "border-radius: 5px; border:#FF0000 1px solid;");
```